# How to paste unformatted text in a xamarin forms editor view by code?

Tags: xamarin

I'm working in a chords transposing app, It has an editor view for the user to paste the lyrics and chords. The problem is that when I hold tap in the entry view to paste the text, in some devices the lyric and chords appear in the same line, It seems It doesn't recognize the "\n" char in some lines from the web text. I've tried to use the clipboard like this:

```
if (Clipboard.HasText)
{
   var textFromWeb = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
   txtSongEntry.Text = textFromWeb;
}
```

It works, but like the first way, just works for some devices.
I've also tried to convert the clipboard text to utf8 but I get the same result.
In some devices there is a function called "paste as unformatted text", If I use this instead of simple paste It works perfect.
Is there any way to clean the clipboard text format before paste it on the editor?
All ideas/suggestion are welcome.
If I'm not clear let me know, English is not my native language :(

Comment: When I copy text from a web and paste in my xamarin forms entry, in some devices it doesn't look like original text in the web site but when I use "paste as unformatted text" it does. Is there anyway to implement an unformatted text editor view?

Comment: Can you try with Editor  instead of entry?

Comment: Sorry, This is what I'm using :)

Comment: In the Android, you can refer to this thread. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#CoerceToText , Coercing the clipboard data to text.